# RandomForestRegressor Example Not Working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to work through a RandomForestRegressor example.  I'm using Python, JupyterLab and sklearn.

I've copied code from https://stackabuse.com/random-forest-algorithm-with-python-and-scikit-learn/

Code is:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# csv from web site above
dataset = pd.read_csv("d:\maternal_health_risk.csv")

y = dataset['BS']
X = dataset.drop(['BS'], axis=1) # You can either include risk level or drop it here

SEED = 42
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=SEED)
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, max_depth=3, random_state=SEED)

X_train, y_train
rfr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm getting an error message from the above that states:

`raise ValueError("sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported.")`

I've looked at y_train object.  Its a Series object with type float64 values.

Not sure what error message means or how to fix.  Thanks.

Comment: The full traceback would be useful to include; please [edit] to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out answer to my question.  `RandomForestRegressor` expects pandas and series inputs to contain only numbers.  I need to drop any columns containing text or replace the text with numbers. In this case the following additional line resolved the issue:

```py
dataset['RiskLevel'] = dataset['RiskLevel'].replace('low risk', 0).replace('mid risk', 1).replace('high risk', 2)
```